# $p$ is an odd primitive, Show why there are no primitive roots of $\bmod 3p$

Tags: number-theory

if $p$ is an odd primitive, Prove there are no primitive roots of $\bmod 3p$

Where I'm at: $a^{2(p-1)}=1 \pmod{3p}$ where a is a primitive root of $3p$ (by contradiction) 
$(a/3p)=(a/3)(a/p)$ are the Legendre symbols, and stuck here..tried a couple of things, but got nowhere, could use a helping hand :]

Comment: So p=3 has a primitive root: 2 generates 2, 4, 8, 7, 5, 1. all the units mod 9.

Answer (score 2):

You mean $p$ is an odd *prime*. (As noted by user58512 one has to take  $p > 3$.)

Try and use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to show that the exponent of the group of units of $\mathbf{Z}_{3 p}$ is at most (actually, exactly) $p-1$, while its order is twice as much.

Comment: But if we use the CRT, we would be able to show that $(Z/{3p})^*$ is not cyclic, hence admitting no primitive roots, right?

Answer (score 2):

is this right?
$a^{p-1}=1 \pmod p$ and
$a^2=1 \pmod 3$
and thus $a^{\operatorname{lcm}(2,p-1)}=1 \pmod {3p}$
but because $p-1$ is even then  $\operatorname{lcm}(2,p-1)<2(p-1)$
and so a is not a  primitive root modulo $3p$?..

Comment: like in the question, $a$ is a primitive root of $3p$ by contradiction

Comment: Spot on! The lcm is of course $p-1$.

Comment: yeah, and so p-1<2*(p-1) and we have a contradiction

Comment: Notice that this argument fails when $p=3$, for then the order of an element is not counted this way, as shown by the examle of user61216.

Answer (score 1):

Counter example: 2 is a primitive root mod (3*3)

Comment: why is this being upvoted? It doesn't answer the question and I wrote this in my answer first.

Comment: @user58512: some people answer before reading all the other answers. I usually delete my answers that turn out to be duplicates, but evidently not everyone does. However, this would probably serve better as a comment to the question, since it points out that the question needs modification, rather than providing an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when $p=3$ the theorem does not hold! 2 is a primitive root.

So supposing $p$ is not 3...

Since $p$ is odd let $p = 2^r k+1$ with $k$ odd.

The group of units is $\mod {3p}$ is $$(\mathbb Z/(3p))^\times \simeq \mathbb Z/(2) \times \mathbb Z/(2^r) \times (\mathbb Z/(k))^\times$$ by Sun Zi's theorem.

There can be no primitive root for this because of the two $\mathbb Z/(2^i)$ parts.

Comment: If $k$ is even, you will have only one factor of order two.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti, I don't understand - I think what I've written is fine whether k is even or odd.

Comment: I assumed p is not 3, but that case........ breaks the theorem..

Comment: @AndreasCaranti, thanks I added a correction now.

Comment: Thanks to peoplepower for another correction.

Comment: You see, $$(\mathbb Z/(3p))^\times \simeq \mathbb Z/(2) \times (\mathbb Z/(p))^\times$$

Now $(\mathbb Z/(p) )^\times$ is cyclic of order $p-1$. And a cyclic group has a direct factor of order 2 if and only if it has order twice an odd number. Please fix.

Comment: And now it's your turn to quote me, don't you think? ;-)

Comment: @AndreasCaranti, no peoplepower helped me in the chat... see my edit  happened before you posted that comment. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7991824#7991824

Comment: and I already thanked you for the bit about p=3 in my comments.

Comment: I believe my first comment (the very first comment to your answer) came before, please check the times.